# Jump to timestamp in HTML5 embedded Video with video-js

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

Greetings overflow,

I'm trying to create buttons on a webpage that jump to tagged timestamps for an embedded video with video-js.  Far as I can gather, I need to change the currentTime value in order to have the video move to the correct timestamp, however I can't get this to work even when setting currentTime in the initial javascript call.

For example, if I wanted to start 200 seconds into the video:

javascript:

```
    VideoJS.setupAllWhenReady();
    VideoJS.DOMReady(function(){
    var myPlayer = VideoJS.setup("current_video");
    myPlayer.play();
    myPlayer.currentTime(200);
    });
```

HTML Snip:

```
<video id="current_video" class="video-js" width="400" height="300" controls="controls" preload="auto" poster="./videoposter.png">
<source src="./videosource.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
</video>
```

Again, the video plays properly using the video-js player, just the currentTime offset doesn't seem to be applied and the video starts from the beginning.  I've tested this in chrome, safari, IE and they all seem to do the same thing so I don't think the problem is browser specific.  I must be doing something wrong...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Same result if you use `myPlayer.currentTime = 200;`?

Comment: Yep, tried this as well.  Have also tried myPlayer.video.currentTime(200);, myPlayer.video.currentTime = 200; etc

Answer (score 4):

Remove the "VideoJS.setupAllWhenReady();" and it should work. This is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Sample styled page</title>
  <script src="video-js/video.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="video-js/video-js.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="Video JS" charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Sample styled page</h1>
  <p>This page is just a demo.</p>
  <video id="current_video" class="video-js" width="400" height="300" controls="controls" preload="auto">
    <source src="pr6.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
  </video>
  <script>
    //VideoJS.setupAllWhenReady();
    VideoJS.DOMReady(function() {
        var myPlayer = VideoJS.setup("current_video");
        myPlayer.play();
        myPlayer.currentTime(200);
    });

  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $(function(){
 var myPlayer = _V_("my_video_1");
     _V_("my_video_1").ready(function(){ 

     myPlayer.src([
      { type: "video/mp4", src: "http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" },
      { type: "video/webm", src: "http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" }
    ]);  

    });
  });

  $(window).load(function(){
  var myPlayer = _V_("my_video_1");

 myPlayer.currentTime(30); 
 myPlayer.play()
  });
```