# Generating graphical timeline in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, html, video, timeline

Let's say I can fetch a total time of an certain video in seconds. I can also get the starting times of sub-events in that video.

Is there a way to output some kind of timeline with sub-events arranged by their starting times respectively to the end time of the video?

The sub-events should also be linked to the video in such way that when I click on them, video would jump on beginning of that sub-event.

Basically, I would like to hide the timeline of html5 video, and stick a new dynamically generated one under the video with few selected events to navigate through, with no slider, just click (for example a tennis match with set and game timeline instead of min:sec timeline).

I'm using video in html5 and javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can user this [jquery plungin](http://timeglider.com/jquery/) for timeline. Would look cool.

And for jumping you can [read here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221344/jump-to-timestamp-in-html5-embedded-video-with-video-js)